# How to escape -exec on find-command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a list of duplicate files on my hard disk. 
I'm having a hard time to check if a file is not on the list.
Grepping

```
grep $1 $2 > /dev/null || echo $1
```

works. But I can't get it to work in the -exec-Part of the find command.

```
find 250G_EXT4/ -type f -exec grep "{}" duplicates_sorted.txt \> /dev/null \|\| echo {} \;
```

The messages are

```
grep: >: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden (File or directory not found)
grep: ||: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden ...
grep: echo: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden ...
```

Has anybody a clue to get the escape sequence right?
Or maybe a different idea?

Comment: `-exec` takes a single command and its arguments; you can't include redirections, which are processed by a shell, not passed to the `exec` system call, or `||`, which is a shell operator for conditional execution.

Comment: Does your file paths contain spaces (or some other naughty character)?

Comment: It does contain spaces and what else naughty things could be found in a filename like umlauts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply

```
find | grep -vFf duplicates_sorted.txt -
```

This should be a lot faster as well.

(The `-F` flag specifies literal matching, i.e. no regex matching. Otherwise `a.c` would match `abc`, etc.)

`find -exec` takes a single command; that single command can be a shell with an arbitrarily complex script passed to it:

```
find -exec sh -c 'grep -q "$1" file || echo "$1"' dummy {} \;
```

The first argument to `sh -c` is used as `$0` so we pass in a dummy placeholder value.

Comment: Although possibly also `-x`, which specifies "match whole lines"; otherwise `a.c` also matches `bodega.c`.

Comment: But the output from `find` will contain a path component which probably isn't in the file.

Comment: +1; good to know how to pass additional parameters to `sh -c` and to be aware of the associated `$0` pitfall - though you can always just use `{}` directly inside the command string.

Comment: Didn't quite grasp the usage of sh but after a minute it seems comprehensible. Thanks for that nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

`-exec` take a single command and its arguments. `> /dev/null` is not an argument, but a redirection that the shell processes before running `grep`. Likewise, `||` is not an argument, but a shell operator used to determine whether or not to run `echo` depending on the exit status of `grep`. To answer your exact question, you need to pass your command list as an argument to `sh -c`.

```
find 250G_EXT4/ -type f \
  -exec sh -c 'grep "{}" duplicates_sorted.txt > /dev/null || echo "{}"' \;
```

Comment: +1, but you should double-quote the `{}` instances to protect them from shell expansions. (Note that this is only necessary inside a command _string_ used with `sh -c`, not when using `{}` as a direct, separate argument).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would use `-q` grep option and don't bother myself with stream redirection. Also I would consider using `fgrep`  (or `grep -F`) instead of `grep` and use `-x` option to match entire plain strings not  regular expressions. And finally I would avoid shell piping.

The resulting command should look like this:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec grep -v -q -x -F {} /path/to/duplicates.txt  \; -print
```

Or something similar depending on your needs.

Comment: This finds those entries which *are* in the file, not the ones which aren't.

Comment: Well probably your answer is better especially that running grep only once on entire find output. But there could be corner cases when a file name contains "bad characters". Not sure if both our answers can correctly handle them.

Comment: `grep` is line-oriented anyway, so this could not work if file names contained newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find duplicate files (i.e. files having the same *content*, independently of their name) I would proceed differently.

I would first compute a checksum, perhaps simply with `md5sum`, for each file, and sort them by their checksum, e.g.

```
find 250G_EXT4/ -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \;   \
  | sort > /tmp/md5sumlist.txt
```

then I would handle those few entries having the same md5 checksum, and use `cmp` to compare their content.

Comment: Well, it already is a list based on md5sums. The handling is the issue.